# Method/tools for batch-converting Microsoft Word files into PDF?

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-office

I have to convert about 2,000 Microsoft Word doc-files into PDFs in Windows. The file names should be the same, only the file extension from .doc in .pdf.

```
doc0001.doc -> doc0001.pdf
doc0002.doc -> doc0002.pdf
...
doc2000.doc -> doc2000.pdf
```

I know this could be done using a pseudo pdf printer driver and adding the documents to the "printer" queue. But I guess this won't work, because I will be prompted for the file name? Or am I wrong?

Is there a different, elegant way to accomplish this task?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this I've used a tool called Convert Doc from a company called SoftInterface.

You point it at a selection of files or a folder, and it'll output your selected Word files as PDF's I've tried it with 2003 and 2007 and it works well. Can be run from a command line if you're so inclined.  The interface of the program could probably do with some work though.

There's a you can download a free trial on their website

[link to product page](http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-Doc/Convert-Doc.htm)

Comment: The UI of that program is scary, but it seems to work. It has many useful options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you install open office this should do the trick: http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html

Answer (score 0):

[PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) is a free open source converter.  It has an auto-save feature that doesn't prompt for destination filename.  It's a little annoying that it only saves to My Documents, Desktop, a temp folder or a custom defined folder and not the targer file's folder but it works rather well.  Select target files, right-click and Print.  Don't know that I'd recommend it for large batches.

Comment: I actually tried PDFCreator, but it didn't work very well. Maybe I should try harder. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I know you said Windows but if you have any Mac owning friends you could ask them to write a very quick/simple 'automator script' using 'preview' to do this.

Comment: I have a mac too. I can open Word docs in Preview?

Comment: Ah, good point, quicklook can but you're right, preview doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If commercial products are a valid option, [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/server/appserver) could be used for this purpose. It provides a PDF printer driver that can be automated using VBScript through an ActiveX control.